# Virtual TTY jumps to the next on launching from the Openbox menu

Tags: console, tty

When I launch a terminal from my Openbox menu my virtual terminal TTY jumps to the next <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> slot.

It seems that this problem appeared after I wanted some more than 7 TTYs and added some to `/etc/inittab`. I don't even know how to formulate a Google search. Every time I launch a terminal from OpenBox I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> - to return back from the terminal I've jumped to.

Here is my /etc/inittab: http://bpaste.net/show/91971/

/var/log/Xorg.0.log: http://bpaste.net/show/153905/

And after a year, as I understand nobody could help at any forum or #gentoo IRC (the question was opened 10 times at different time ..or so)

Yes, the system could live, though it's somehow annoying.

**/update:** The problem worsened from just jumping through TTY's to desktop not reacting on a mouse second time after the first successful launch of lxterminal/xfce-terminal ....etc.. etc... dozens of them (including xterm)

---

I'm adding my configs

```
cat /proc/cmdline
root=/dev/sda2
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Updated some configs to the problem. Btw I've found another issue http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7450526.html It's as mine. But dissapeared. Mine lasts for more than a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I answer my own nagging question, for I've got help from another forum. Then I did a little googling AND:

I had removed startx from ~/.bashrc - as non-login sript. Instead I wrote to the end of:

```
~/.bash_profile
...
startx
```

.bash_profile - is nogin-script only executed on login ONCE.

So, I guess, the effect was like this: NEXT TTY when I launched any terminal emulator every time.